# I am not able to open SharePoint Central Administrator

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, installation

I have install all the Required software for SharePoint foundation 2010, VS2010, SQL Server 2008 in windows 7 64 bit,

Everything install properly but when I am going to open central admin from program menu, my IE browser sometimes opens 
 Pagenot Found, sometimes
HTTP 500 internal server error,
some time Internet Explorer cannot display the page.

Previous by default IIS install 6.0, now I have Changed to IIS7.0  installed and I am trying but not able to solve the IE issue.

What is the Exactly issue in my IIS and browser?

Answer (score 1):

Find a webconfig for the CA site and disable custom error:

1. Change CallStack="false" to CallStack="true" (in safemode element)
2. Change debug="false" to debug="true"
3. Change  to

Then try to open CA again and show us the error description.

Also I recommend to check ULS logs.

Answer (score 0):

One of the possibility for getting Internal server 500 error is non-functioning application pool.

Check whether application pool for central administration is running or not. If its not running just start it otherwise try stopping and again starting. After doing this refresh the page and check whether its working or not.

Answer (score 0):

Run the SharePoint Configuration wizard again on your farm. If its runs successfully and issue still persists, then there might be some issue with your IIS or SQL.